# Custom Database structure to Wordpress database structure

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a custom database structure like this

### Post

-postid

-post

-categoryid

### Category

-categoryid

-name

how to make it a wordpress post and category ? it's like bulk insert from other database.

Thanks

Comment: maybe consider using the wordpress CLI as this will ensure that the  wordpress tables would be updated in a consistent manner https://wp-cli.org/commands/post/

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins that can easily handle this task. For example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/ . You can curate a .csv file with the data you want to import and then use the plugin to map the columns to specific WordPressfields and post meta. However, trying to add posts into WordPress with the same post ids from another database will be problematic. This is because is WordPress, almost everything is stored as a "post", and the ids you want to use may already be in the existing WordPress database. I believe the plugin will not let you set the post id anyway. A better way would allow WordPress to assign the id and store the id from your other database in a custom post meta field. This would allow you to still access that information inside of WordPress